# What is the replacement for Spring's deprecated NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

The `NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException` was deprecated in Spring 4.3, in favor of [annotation-driven handler methods](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/multiaction/NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException.html). What does this mean? The exception is still listed in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-rest-spring-mvc-exceptions), without mentioning its deprecated status. If I understand correctly, this exception is thrown when there is no request mapper for a given request. It appears to be handled by the `DefaultExceptionHandlerResolver`, [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.html), and the relevant method has been deprecated as well.

If this method is deprecated, can I assume Spring does not throw this exception anymore? How am I supposed to replace this functionality with annotation-driven exception handling? Which exception am I supposed to handle, if this one is deprecated?

**Side note:** I also noticed a newer `NoHandlerFoundException`, [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/NoHandlerFoundException.html). Is this a replacement? If so, why? It appears to do the same thing. And why are the exceptions related to other HTTP status codes not deprecated? It all doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: The `NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException` stems from the fact that there was once a `MultiActionController` as this has been deprecated that also goes for the accompanying classes (like the exception). Also your understanding is wrong, it is thrown from within the `MultiActionController` which throws it if it cannot find a method. It isn't part of the generic exception handling like the `NoHandlerFoundException`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for the clarification! So this exception will never be thrown by Spring itself? And if I want to handle generic 404s, I should be handling the `NoHandlerFoundException`?

Comment: It will be thrown by a specific deprecated component of Spring, hence the deprecation of the rest.

Comment: @M.Deinum Ah, I see, thank you. So if I have no `MultiActionController` instances (or any other multiaction classes), I can safely ignore this exception. And use `NoHandlerFoundException` to handle unmapped requests.

Comment: Exactly. And the whole `MultiActionController` (and thus accompanying objects/methods) stuff has been deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

The NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException exception is part of the multiaction package that has been deprecated in Spring:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/multiaction/class-use/NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException.html

If you don't use multiactions, you can safely get rid of that catch statement and/or stop trying to catch and handle that exception. For example, some "Exception-to-Response error handlers" sample code might look like this to try and catch cases when the dispatcher doesn't find a proper mapping:

```
   @ControllerAdvice
public class RestErrorHandler {

  @ExceptionHandler({FileNotFoundException.class, NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException.class})
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
  @ResponseBody
  public ErrorInfo process404(HttpServletRequest req, Exception ex) {
    return handleException(req, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, ex);
  }
}
```

But the latest dispatcher (non-multiaction) will never throw such an exception, so you could simply get rid of the NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException and, instead, handle the NoHandlerFoundException (which is not thrown by default, but you can configure the spring dispatcher to throw it IF you really need to, because, by default, the dispatcher already returns a 404).